# Cómo puedo deslizar un div de arriba hacía abajo al darle clic a cerrar?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

realicé este simple reproductor con HTML, CSS y algo de JS pero no encuentro la manera de hacer que al dar clic en la X el div se deslice hacía abajo, quede "oculto" y que luego la X cambie a un icono hacía arriba o a la palabrar abrir para que al darle clic nuevamente vuelva a subir el div. (Actualmente lo tengo con el efecto **toggle**)

Les agradecería mucho si me pudiesen ayudar.

A continuación les dejo el código completo del reproductor

```js
/* Función ocultar para el reproductor */
function ocultar(){
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".cerrar").click(function(){
    jQuery("#caja").slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

```css
#contenedor {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 26;
    width: 420px;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#caja{
position: absolute;
width: 420px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
height:100px;
}
#miniatura{
z-index: 25;
float: left;
padding-right: 10px;
}
#sonando{
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
padding-top: 5px;
}
#reproductor{
margin-top: -10px;
}
#ocultar{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: inherit;
    padding-right: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
    <div id="ocultar">
<span class="cerrar">X</span>
    </div>
<div id="caja">
<div id="miniatura">
    <img class="cc_streaminfo" width="100px" height="auto" data-type="trackimageurl" data-username="laonda2" alt="La Onda" />
</div>
<div id="sonando">
    <strong><span class="cc_streaminfo" data-type="tracktitle" data-username="laonda2" style="color: #fff;"></span></strong><br />
<span class="cc_streaminfo" data-type="trackartist" data-username="laonda2"></span><br />
    </div>
    <div id="reproductor">
        <audio id="audio_1" autoplay controls="" preload="none" style="width:19em;padding:0;height:35px;margin:20px auto"><source src="" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
     </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

La función `ocultar()` que tienes definida no se está llamando en ningún momento, por lo que no se va a ejecutar. Además tienes problemas de sintaxis (como una etiqueta `<script>` dentro de la función) que provocan que el código arroje un error.

He rescatado de tu código la función anónima que ejecutas con el "document ready", que hace lo que pretendes.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".cerrar").click(function(){
    jQuery("#caja").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#contenedor {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 26;
    width: 420px;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#caja{
position: absolute;
width: 420px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
height:100px;
}
#miniatura{
z-index: 25;
float: left;
padding-right: 10px;
}
#sonando{
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
padding-top: 5px;
}
#reproductor{
margin-top: -10px;
}
#ocultar{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: inherit;
    padding-right: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor">
    <div id="ocultar">
<span class="cerrar">X</span>
    </div>
<div id="caja">
<div id="miniatura">
    <img class="cc_streaminfo" width="100px" height="auto" data-type="trackimageurl" data-username="laonda2" alt="La Onda" />
</div>
<div id="sonando">
    <strong><span class="cc_streaminfo" data-type="tracktitle" data-username="laonda2" style="color: #fff;"></span></strong><br />
<span class="cc_streaminfo" data-type="trackartist" data-username="laonda2"></span><br />
    </div>
    <div id="reproductor">
        <audio id="audio_1" autoplay controls="" preload="none" style="width:19em;padding:0;height:35px;margin:20px auto"><source src="" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
     </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Como extra, añado que `jQuery(document).ready()` está en desuso, así que te recomienda usar en su lugar:

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery(".cerrar").click(function(){
    jQuery("#caja").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, es muy valiosa, sin embargo el efecto toggle no es lo que busco, ya que el div se desliza hacía arriba